# PHP/MYSQL -update inside of looping. slow to load page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a working update query using mysql but currently it is very slow to load the page. Is there any way to make more faster the update of my query?.

**Here's my code**

```
<?php

    $sql = "select ite_desc,ecr_desc, pric_cash, t.itemcode  as itemcode ,sum(t.qty) as qty
        from ( 
    select ite_desc,ecr_desc,  pric_cash,   itemcode,qty  from barcode as bc inner JOIN allinvty3 as ait on bc.itemcode = ait.in_code
    union all
    select ite_desc,ecr_desc,  pric_cash,   itemcode,qty  from branchtobranch_tb as bb inner JOIN allinvty3 as ait on bb.itemcode = ait.in_code
    union all
    select ite_desc,ecr_desc,    pric_cash, itemcode,qty from adjustment_tb as adt inner JOIN allinvty3 as ait1 on adt.itemcode = ait1.in_code where adt.status='APPROVED'
    union all
    select ite_desc,ecr_desc,  pric_cash,   itemcode,qty  from stockreturn_tb as sb inner JOIN allinvty3 as ait on sb.itemcode = ait.in_code
    union all
    select ite_desc,ecr_desc,  pric_cash,   itemcode,qty  from notinclude_tb as nt inner JOIN allinvty3 as ait on nt.itemcode = ait.in_code where nt.status='COMPLETE'
    union all
    select ite_desc,ecr_desc,  pric_cash,   itemcode,qty  from purchase_tb as pt inner JOIN allinvty3 as ait on pt.itemcode = ait.in_code 
    union all
    select ite_desc,ecr_desc,   pric_cash, itemcode,(qty * -1) from soldout_pd as slp inner JOIN allinvty3 as ait2 on slp.itemcode = ait2.in_code) as t
    group by itemcode order by ecr_desc  ASC ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    echo "

    </tr>";
    // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $total =$row['qty'];
    $itemcode=$row['itemcode'];
    $sql1="UPDATE allinvty3 set sa_onhand = '".$total."' where in_code ='".$itemcode."'" ;
    $conn->query($sql1);
    }echo " </table>";}
    ?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this as a single query:

```
update allinvty3 a join
       (select t.itemcode, sum(t.qty) as qty
        from ((select ite_desc,ecr_desc,  pric_cash, itemcode, qty
               from barcode bc inner join
                    allinvty3 ait
                    on bc.itemcode = ait.in_code
              ) union all
              (select ite_desc, ecr_desc, pric_cash, itemcode, qty
               from branchtobranch_tb bb inner join
                    allinvty3 ait
                    on bb.itemcode = ait.in_code
              ) union all
              (select ite_desc, ecr_desc, pric_cash, itemcode, qty
               from adjustment_tb adt inner join
                    allinvty3 ait1
                    on adt.itemcode = ait1.in_code
               where adt.status = 'APPROVED'
              ) union all
              (select ite_desc, ecr_desc, pric_cash, itemcode, qty
               from stockreturn_tb sb inner join
                    allinvty3 ait
                    on sb.itemcode = ait.in_code
              ) union all
              (select ite_desc, ecr_desc, pric_cash, itemcode, qty
               from notinclude_tb nt inner join
                    allinvty3 ait
                    on nt.itemcode = ait.in_code
               where nt.status='COMPLETE'
              ) union all
              (select ite_desc, ecr_desc, pric_cash, itemcode, qty
               from purchase_tb pt inner join
                    allinvty3 ait
                    on pt.itemcode = ait.in_code 
              ) union all
              (select ite_desc, ecr_desc, pric_cash, itemcode, (qty * -1) 
               from soldout_pd slp inner join
                    allinvty3 ait2
                    on slp.itemcode = ait2.in_code
              )
             ) t
        group by itemcode
       ) i
       on a.in_code = i.itemcode
    set a.sa_onhand = i.qty;
```

This will at least get rid of the `update` loop, letting the database do the work rather than application.  If performance is an issue, then it is probably the `union all`.  If that is the case, you have to investigate each subquery.